# Stream audio directly from browser to server

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, mediastream, web-mediarecorder

I'd like to start uploading audio recorded from a mic as soon as the user hits *Record*, rather than wait until they're done. Is this possible with browser JavaScript?

I tried this just to get started, but the request ends immediately instead of continuing as long as the recorder is recording.

#### Client (browser) code

```js
navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ audio: true }).then(
  (stream) => {
    const recorder = new MediaRecorder(stream)

    recorder.onstart = async () => {
      await fetch("/stream/upload", {
        method: "POST",
        headers: { "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data" },
        body: stream,
        allowHTTP1ForStreamingUpload: true,
      })

      console.log("Upload complete!")
    }
  },
  (err) => console.error("Error: " + err)
)
```

#### Server code

```js
const app = express()

app.post("/stream/upload", (req, res, next) => {
  res.status(200)

  req.on("data", (chunk) => {
    // only appears once
    console.log("Data received")
    res.write(chunk)
  })

  req.on("end", () => {
    // and then this appears immediately after
    console.log("Stream ended")
    res.send("Ended")
  })
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onstart` is only called when the recording start - you need to instead upload data as part of the [`dataavailable` event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaRecorder/ondataavailable) - to make that event happen more frequently, use the `timeslice` parameter of the `start` method.

That being said, depending on the underlying use case, you may be better served by using WebRTC to stream the audio content to the server.

Comment: Thank you. I didn't want to use the dataavailable event because that would create a new connection for each event instead of streaming over one connection. Unfortunately support for streaming requests via fetch API isn't ready for prime time. It looks like WebRTC is the way to accomplish what I want.

Comment: an alternative to using fetch would be to set up a WebSocket server and send the bytes over web socket. Setting up a websocket endpoint is probably easier than setting up a WebRTC connection

Comment: Thanks! I'll look into that too. I thought that'd be hard but now that I'm spurred to look into it some more I think it can be done more simply than I thought.